# Malloc error after running chown -R on /usr/

Tags: terminal, chown, homebrew

I'm running Yosemite on a macbook air.

I was following the suggestions after running `brew doctor` which told me that `usr/local` did not have write access. It told me to run `chown` on a bunch of directories in `usr/`. Not particularly knowing what I was doing, I `chown -R`ed all of `/usr/` and now I get this blaring error message whenever I open the terminal:

```
Last login: Wed May 20 08:59:06 on console
login(592,0x7fff7cacc300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9d0ac10c90: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]
```

What in the world do I do now? Can I do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Open Disk Utility by entering *"Disk Utility"* in spotlight and waiting for Disk Utility to appear, or by opening it through any other means.

In Disk Utility, select the OS partition on your internal drive<sup>1</sup> and click the `Repair Disk Permissions` button.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. Typically called "Macintosh HD" and "Internal Drive", respectively.